# O365 site throwing HTTPS Security errors

Tags: office-365, error, https

I have an O365 publishing site that is mostly out-of-box except that it uses a custom master page which implements a little custom CSS. However when looking at the console in IE every time the site loads I see the following errors:

```
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/forbidframing.htm
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/errorPageStrings.js
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/httpErrorPagesScripts.js
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/red_x.png
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/bullet.png
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/background_gradient.jpg
```

I've looked around online and found people discussing iframes and ajax queries but none of those are included in this site outside of what O365 does by default. Why would this environment be throwing these errors?